# Android ping tool with audible ping

Tags: android, networking

I'd like an Android ping tool (as in, [ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) another computer on the network) that includes audible output.

- Pings selected computer (IP or hostname) on the local network until stopped.
- Generates a sound on each ping reply.
- Free would be nice, but I'm willing to pay a reasonable amount for such a tool.

The objective is that I can start a ping on my phone, then set the phone down nearby while I start fiddling with cables in the rack, and I'll know if I pull the cable to the computer I'm pinging.

Comment: I think that you are asking for a tool that pings a remote computer and makes a noise when the __reply__ is received - if so it might be a good idea to edit your question to make that more apparent as it also reads as if you are expecting a noise from the remote computer.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: Fair enough. If you don't know ping that could be very confusing, I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a networker and I use this app for examine my networking task, but I don't think it has an audible sound. It's a multi-thread secured network app that suit for Pinging
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nristek.apps.netztools